# Spivak, Ch 4 Appendix 3 - Polar Coordinates, Problem 5: interpreting signs in last step of derivation of polar equation of hyperbola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

This question is about the final step in the derivation of the equation of a hyperbola in polar coordinates, as seen in Spivak's book Calculus, Chapter 4 Appendix 3 on Polar Coordinates, problem 5.

[image]

**Here is my question, and I will provide the detailed equations below if necessary for someone.**

The equation for the right side of the hyperbola above in polar coordinates is:

$$r=\Lambda-\epsilon r \cos{\theta}\tag{1}$$

$$\implies r = \frac{\Lambda}{1+\epsilon \cos{\theta}}\tag{2}$$

$$\Lambda=a(1-\epsilon^2)$$

In the derivation below, the equation for the left side of the hyperbola is

$$r = -(\Lambda-\epsilon r \cos{\theta})\tag{3}$$

So it seems like $(3)$ is just the negative of $(1)$, as one would expect.

However, if I isolate $r$ I get

$$r(1-\epsilon\cos{\theta})=-\Lambda$$

$$\implies r = \frac{-\Lambda}{1-\epsilon\cos{\theta}}\tag{4}$$

My question seems to be about simple algebra:

**I can't see how $(4)$ is the negative of $(2)$ because of the minus sign in the denominator. What am I missing?**

**Here is the derivation for the right side of the hyperbola**

The square of distance from $(x,y)$ to the focus at $(0,0)$ is

$$r^2 = x^2 + y^2$$

The square of the distance from $(x,y)$ to the focus at $(-2\epsilon a,0)$ is

$$s^2 = (x+2\epsilon a)^2 + y^2 = x^2 +4\epsilon a x + 4 \epsilon^2a^2 + y^2$$

By definition of hyperbola, $r-s=\pm 2a$.

Let's consider first the case where $r-s=2a$, ie the right side of the hyperbola.

$$s = r - 2a$$
$$s^2 = r^2 -4ar+4a^2$$

Equate the two expressions we have for $s^2$ and simplify

$$r^2 -4ar+4a^2 = x^2 +4\epsilon a x + 4 \epsilon^2a^2 + y^2$$

$$a^2-ar = \epsilon ax + \epsilon^2a^2$$

$$a-r=\epsilon x + \epsilon^2a$$

$$r = a-\epsilon x - \epsilon^2 a$$

$$r = a(1-\epsilon^2) - \epsilon x$$

If we define $\Lambda=a(1-\epsilon^2)$ we have

$$r = \Lambda - \epsilon r x$$

use $x=r\cos{\theta}$

$$r = \Lambda - \epsilon r \cos{\theta}$$

$$r = \frac{\Lambda}{1+\epsilon \cos{\theta}}$$

**Now for the left side of the hyperbola** This is essentially the same as the first part except for a sign, so I'll make it quick:

$$r-s=-2a$$

$$\implies s = r+2a$$

$$s^2 = r^2 + 4ar +4a^2$$

$$r^2 +4ar+4a^2 = x^2 +4\epsilon a x + 4 \epsilon^2a^2 + y^2$$

$$a+r=\epsilon x + \epsilon^2a$$

$$r = -a + \epsilon x + \epsilon^2a = -a(1-\epsilon^2)+\epsilon x$$
$$r = -\Lambda + \epsilon x = -(\Lambda - \epsilon x)$$